# cell phone detector circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, detection, mobile

i have successfully implimented below circuit for active cell phone detection but i dont seem to understand the working of this circuit,if someone could explain it would be a great help.Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I think they work as huge gain amplifiers. So antenna picks some electricity, charges c2 a little which than is amplified and produces some voltage difference which lights the led.

Comment: It's not specifically a cell phone detector - it will likely detect any reasonably sized electric field of almost any reasonable frequency thus making it an electric field detector. Is this what you wanted to build?

Comment: The LM358 has a unity-gain bandwidth of only about 0.7 MHz, so in this case it's not really used to amplify the GHz signal from the antenna. See [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/183756/102305) for further speculation and a potentially "real answer" to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

As Andy Aka has pointed out this is an alternating electric field detector. I'm no expert on radio but this circuit is easy enough to understand.

- U1-A is wired as an inverting amplifier. R1 and R2 bias the + input to half-supply voltage (BAT+ / 2).
- R3 is the amplifier feedback resistor but the usual inverting mode input resistor is missing. Therefore the input antenna will provide alternating *current* to the virtual earth of the inverting input. For every nA of current flowing towards the inverting input the output will decrease by \$ 1~nA \cdot 6.8~M\Omega = 6.8~mV\$ (to keep the inverting input at the same potential as the non-inverting input).
- U1-B is configured as a comparitor. The inverting input is held at a reference voltage by sensitivity adjust pot R5. In setup this would be adjusted downwards until LED D1 turns off. (For LED off, pin 7 must be high so inverting input must be lower than non-inverting input.)
- When the antenna signal is strong enough U1-A output will oscillate about the half-supply point and when it goes below the threshold set by R5 the LED will begin to light.

Comment: that was quiet an interesting explanation thank you for the explanation now i know how it works...

Comment: I'm glad it helped. If no better answer turns up and you're happy that this one answers your question then please click the "accept" icon.

Answer (score 1):

Non-inverting amplifier (Op-Amp 1), is used for amplify signal from antenna,
as to make suitable to drive LED and buzzer op-amp (Op-Amp 2) with only positive supply is used. Upon change in input of driver op-amp, it'll be reflected on LED and buzzer.

Comment: The LM358 has a unity-gain bandwidth of only about 0.7 MHz, so in this case it's not really used to amplify the GHz signal from the antenna. See [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/183756/102305) for further speculation.